# Google Cloud Pub/Sub - Capture message delivery failure reason to messages sent to Dead Letter Topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to configure a Pub/Sub subscription with a dead-letter topic (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics).
The messages are published on the dead letter topic whenever the Cloud Run service returns a 400/500 http response code (NACK).
Is it possible to somehow pass the failure reason (maybe as a message attribute) when message is being published to the dead letter topic ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a feature. It could seem interesting but it's in reality very complex. Indeed, the minimum number of retry is 5, and  you can have 5 different failures. And thus, you can expect, as attribute the list of all these failures? Only the last one? Is the last one the most relevant? And if you set more than 5 retries, do you want all the error code/error messages of all the try?

You can open a feature request if you want [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) and describe your business case. It might be taken into account.